# java sound api AudioSystem.getMixerInfo() issue

Tags: java, api, audio

i'm trying to make some simple audiorecorder-player from line-in but i've faced a really annoying problem: When i'm trying to AudioSystem.getMixerInfo() and printout list of available Mixer, i'm getting

```
????????? ???????? ??????? 
???????? (SoundMAX Integrated Digital HD Audio) 
????????? SPDIF (SoundMAX Integrated Digital HD Audio) 
????????? ??????? ?????? ????? 
????? ?????????? (SoundMAX Inte 
???. ???? (SoundMAX Integrated 
Java Sound Audio Engine 
Port ???????? (SoundMAX Integrated D 
Port ????????? SPDIF (SoundMAX Integ 
Port ???. ???? (SoundMAX Integrated  
Port ????? ?????????? (SoundMAX Inte
```

Sorry?don't know how to format text, so i placed \n to mark where the line ends.

i can't understand what device to select because i can't even read nor russian description nor device name in most lines. Currently i'm using Win & x64 Russian Language.
is it possible to solve somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late with answer. But maybe this will help you or someone else facing same issue. 
I managed to solve it by properly decoding device name.

```
 byte bytes[] = deviceName.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); // <- from
 String value = new String(bytes, "Windows-1251"); // <- to
```

Full code will be something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    for(int i = 0; i < mixerInfo.length; i++)
    {
        String deviceName = mixerInfo[i].getName();

        byte bytes[] = deviceName.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); // <- from
        String value = new String(bytes, "Windows-1251"); // <- to

        System.out.println(value);

    }

}
```

And the output:

```
Primary Sound Driver
Динамики (Realtek High Definition Audio)
C24F390 (Аудио Intel(R) для дисплеев)
Port Динамики (Realtek High Definiti
Port C24F390 (Аудио Intel(R))
```